# Render element using map in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, jsx

I have a variable called `brands` which is a list. Under `return` in `render`, when I try to map over the list and create new paragraph tag, I get this error: `Expected to return a value in arrow function  array-callback-return`.

```
var brands = [];

componentDidMount(){
    database.ref("/brands/").on('child_added', (snapshot)=>{
        var data = snapshot.val();
        console.log(data);
        brands.push(data);
    })
}

render(){
    return(
        <div>
            {brands.map((brand)=>{
                <p>{brand}</p>
            }
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: You might want to put `brands` in state. Since it won't re-render the component until the state has been changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a `return` statement to your arrow function and it will work as expected:

```
render() {
  return(
     <div>
       {brands.map((brand) => {
         return <p>{brand}</p>;
       })}
     </div>
   )
}
```

You could also change `{}` to `()` to get an implicit return:

```
render() {
  return(
    <div>
      {brands.map((brand) => (
        <p>{brand}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

You also have to put your `brands` in state so the component will re-render when `brands` update. Make sure not to push to the array, since that will mutate it.

**Example**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { brands: [] };

  componentDidMount() {
    database.ref("/brands/").on("child_added", snapshot => {
      var data = snapshot.val();
      this.setState(previousState => {
        return { brands: [...previousState.brands, data] };
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.brands.map((brand, index) => (
          <p key={index}>{brand}</p>;
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for sparing time. The error which I was getting has been fixed but I still do not see the output in HTML DOM.

Comment: @Vedant You're welcome! That's frustrating. Could you include your entire component in the question? It's hard to say if `brands` comes from your state, or if it is a regular array outside of the component, etc.

Comment: It is a regular array outside of the component. Does this make any difference?

Comment: @Vedant Ah, I see. Yes, that will sadly not work. A component is re-rendered when the props or the state changes, so storing the brands in an external array will not cause a re-render. It might be worth creating a new question with your entire component, since this particular error has been resolved.

Comment: @Vedant yes..```this.state.brands``` vs ```brands```

Comment: @Vedant I updated my answer with an example of how you can use brands in the component state instead.

Comment: a very useful tool would be to configure eslint and prettier with your code - it will save a lot of headache around a lot of JS errors, even ones like these where you were not returning anything from an arrow function ([babel-no-unused-expressions](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-expressions)).

Answer (score 0):

You may also drop the braces like this:
`{ brands.map(brand => <p>{brand}</p>) }`

Answer (score 0):

i suggest to use **function** and **return**, and use **state** to store your `brands`

```
import _ from 'lodash';

constructor() {
   super();
   this.state = {
     brands: []
   }
}

componentDidMount(){
    let newData = [];
    database.ref("/brands/").on('child_added', (snapshot)=>{
        let data = snapshot.val();
        console.log(data);
        newData.push(data);
    });

    this.setState({
         brands: newData
    });
}

renderBrand = () => {
  return _.map(this.state.brands, (brand, i) => {
     return <p>{brand}</p>;
  });
}

render(){
    return(
        <div>
            { this.renderBrand() }
        </div>
    )
}
```